# md-autocomplete number of items displayed

Tags: angular-material, md-autocomplete

What controls the number of items displayed in a drop down list for md-autocomplete.

I have space for more than the 5 that are being displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean increase the height of the autocomplete results container? If that's the case, this is not yet posible with `angular-material` out of the box. See this [closed issue](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/5132).

As it's posted in an issue comment, as a workaround you can use a little css hack. Something like this:

```
.md-virtual-repeat-container.md-autocomplete-suggestions-container {
    height: 350px;
    max-height: 350px !important;
}
```

You can see it working on [this plunker](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbajBP). Hope it helps

Comment: This was even better: .md-virtual-repeat-container.md-autocomplete-suggestions-container {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 50px !important;
    height: initial !important;
    max-height: 99999999px !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

use `md-dropdown-items="7"`

Sourced from the issue [linked](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/5132) above.